# PHPspec assign value and test update

Tags: php, oop, phpspec

I have the following class

```
class Customer {}
```

and it has properties like Id, Name, City and Country and methods like findById and findByCity. I want to write a spec test that will test that my Customer::save() function works like this

```
function it_should_update_customer_name_on_save()
{
$customer = $this->findById(1);
$customer->Name = 'Compu-Global-Hyper-Mega-Net';
$customer->save();

$this->findById(1)->shouldReturn('Compu-Global-Hyper-Mega-Net');
}
```

but phpspec keeps throwing this error back at me

```
! it should update name on save (111ms)
        error: Argument 1 passed to PHPSpec2\Wrapper\ArgumentsUnwrapper::unwrapAll() must be of the type array, string given,
        called in /Users/kristiannissen/Documents/php/phpecosrv/vendor/phpspec/phpspec2/src/PHPSpec2/Prophet/ObjectProphet.php
        on line 126 and defined in
        /Users/kristiannissen/Documents/php/phpecosrv/vendor/phpspec/phpspec2/src/PHPSpec2/Wrapper/ArgumentsUnwrapper.php line
        10
```

how should I perform this kind of test?

Comment: If it's not a ton of code, could you give us enough to reproduce the error ourselves? :)

Comment: $customer = $this->findById(1); returns a new instance of Customer(). But how would you go about making this kind of test in phpspec? 1) find an existing object, 2) alter it's values, 3) save it, 4) test that the change has taken place

Comment: @kristiannissen I suggest you go and read the phpspec manual first. You seem to be missing fairly basic concepts: http://www.phpspec.net/en/latest/manual/introduction.html Also read: http://techportal.inviqa.com/2013/07/23/php-test-doubles-patterns-with-prophecy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing an integration test between your model and the database, that's not the goal of phpspec.
The saving responsability of the Customer should not be inside the customer Class anyway, it should be in a domain service.
`findById` should be performed by a repository class, and `save` by an entity manager class, inject both, and mock them.